# html_entities Vs strip_tags with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, html-entities, mysql-real-escape-string, strip-tags

I have a question upon **Strip_tags**, **html_entities** and **mysql_real_escape_string**.

Now when I use for example:

```
strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
```

This code above will be safe as well as this:

```
html_entities($_POST['username']);
```

Which one is more safer for a real world project.

And what is the the benefit for using **strip_tags** and **mysql_real_escape_string** together. But when I use html_entities with them it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear purpose at first. There's no all-around escapeing.

## [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

### Purpose

Display user inputs as **HTML**.

### Example

```
<div><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['data'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?></div>
```

### Note

Use this function when you just about to display it. Do not apply it to store into variables beforehand.

> Has this variable been already escaped...?

... You may trouble yourself.

## [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Do not use this function. SANITIZE is a wrong way.

## [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

### Purpose

Set user inputs in **SQL**.

### Example

```
<?php
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '%s' AND address = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'], $link),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address'], $link)
);
```

### Note

`mysql_*` functions are all **deprecated**. You'd better use `PDO`. `PDO` provides us **Prepared Statements** and **Placeholders**, instead of escaping.

**[PHP Manual - PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)**